# php html form valid email check and post

Tags: php

I am creating PHP contact form validation script my script email filed error message display but it's inserting not valid email to database I want to insert valid email only

Here is my code

```php
<?php 
$nameErr = $emailErr = $messageErr= "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "title is required";
    } else {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $messageErr = "Message is required";
    } else {
        $message = $_POST["message"];
    }

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO contact
    (name,email,message,id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name,$email,$message,$id);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "Your project added successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Failed added your project";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, you're doing validation but even if the validation fails, you're going right along and adding to the database anyway.

Comment: Did you really not indent your code, or is this a side-effect of the SO entry system?

Comment: You can validate emails using filter_var. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is doing this:

```
if POST
  if no input name
    error message
  else
    name = input name
  if no input email
    error message
  else
    email = input email
  if no input message
    error message
  else
    message = input message

  insert name/email/message as a new entry
```

Even though you set error messages in your if/else statements, you still insert the record into your database in the end. You need to somehow check for errors before deciding whether or not to insert the record. replacing the last part of your code with something along the lines of this may give you the result you're looking for:

```
if ( $nameErr != "" && $emailErr != "" && $messageErr != "" ) {
  $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO contact(name,email,message,id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"); 
  $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name,$email,$message,$id);
  if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Your project added successfully";
  } else {
    echo "Failed to add your project";
  }
} else {
  echo "Failed to add your project";
}
```

Comment: I added but same results